# Extract pattern from a string in a bash script

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

Somewhat new to bash.

I've experimented with parameter expansions, grep, sed and echo to solve this problem, but cannot quite work it out.

I'm trying to extract a certain pattern from $PWD in a bash script.

Let's say there could be a variety of full paths:

```
/home/files/tmp8
/home/tmp28/essential
/home/tmp2/essential/log
/home/files/tmp10/executables
/tmp8/files/whatever/etc
```

In every instance, I want to extract any string that contains "tmp" followed by 1 or more integers.

So, in each instance in which $PWD is processed, it will return "tmp8", "tmp28", "tmp2" etc.

Explanations for how the functions/operators work in regards to solving this issue would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -o` to show only matched text using regex `tmp[0-9]*` i.e. literal text `tmp` followed by 0 or more digits:

```
grep -o 'tmp[0-9]*' file
tmp8
tmp28
tmp2
tmp10
tmp8
```

Comment: Thank you for both explanations. Can I use these to assign the extracted pattern to a string or to use it in another command?

Comment: Yes sure you can do `str=$(grep -o 'tmp[0-9]*' <<< "$PWD")` to assign extracted pattern to a variable `str`

Comment: `grep -o 'tmp[0-9]*' <<< "$PWD"` only returns matched string i.e. `tmp<integer>` not the full input.

Comment: The regex 'tmp[0-9]*' is not correct. That one also matches 'tmp' without a following digit. The star means any cardinality including zero.

Comment: Of course I know that. If OP always wants 1 or more digits after `tmp` then OP can use; `grep -Eo 'tmp[0-9]+' <<< "$PWD"`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it works with "pset" followed by one or more numeric digits. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use regular expressions in bash to extract a pattern from any path string. See the following example:

```
if [[ "$PWD" =~ ^.*(tmp[0-9]+).*$ ]]
then
    printf "match: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\n"
else
    printf "no match: $PWD\n"
fi
```

The regular expression defines a group in the round parenthesis.
If the expression matches the matching group (tmp with at least one digit following) it will be stored by Bash in the array BASH_REMATCH.